# How to enforce a 5-minute per post rule in a session object in Java?

Tags: java, date, wicket

I'm trying to figure out how to enforce a 5 minute per post/action rule.

I'm developing a web application with Wicket in Java and I've got a session class which I was planning on using to keep track of these timers on a per-user basis. I wasn't planning on storing the timestamp in a database.

I've got the method below in my session class, and now I'm trying to figure out how to go about storing and checking that there's a 5 minute difference between the last time the user posted and the current time.

If, lets say java.util.Date, would be suitable for this, how do I get the difference between two of these, in minutes.

```
public boolean isAllowedToPost() {  
    if(null OR has 5 minutes passed since last post) {  
        // set the new timestamp      
        return true;    
    }  
    else   
    {   
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: There isn't usually a single "right" way to write code that's any more specific than "don't do it wrong"; what exactly are you wanting to ask here?

Comment: I'm sorry if the "right way" threw you off track. What I'm asking is how do I accomplish what I explained in the title of this question?

For example, how would I go about storing a Date object and subtracting this to check if there's a 5 minute time difference or greater? Would it be overkill to store one Date object in each session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most robust way would be storing the timestamp in a database, since the client could simply logout/login or trash the session (delete cookie or restart webbrowser) to obtain a new session.

If you insist in storing it in session at any way, then one of the ways would be setting the timestamp during `post()` and use it as comparision material in `isAllowedToPost()`. You can obtain the current timestamp by [`System#currentTimeMillis()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29). No need for `java.util.Date`.

Kickoff example (assuming that this whole bean is session scoped):

```
private static final long MAX_WAIT_FOR_POST = 300000L; // ..ms = 5 minutes.
private long lastPost; // Defaults to 0 anyway.

public void post() {
    lastPost = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // ...
}

public boolean isAllowedToPost() {
    return (lastPost + MAX_WAIT_FOR_POST) < System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I appreciate the input on why I should store the timestamp in the database and not in the session. I haven't set up any database connectivity yet so that's why I want to store it in the session for the time being.

Thanks again.